# WebRTC iOS 13 Simulator - Red Screen H264 Decoding

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

My problem is that H264 WebRTC Video is playing on iOS 13 in real device as expected. 
But it does not play in iOS 13 simulator. It shows red screen as shown in the image. 
Audio is playing correctly. Logs also show that decoding of frames are succesful at correct rate.

[image]

GoogleWebRTC version is 1.1.29229 from cocoapods

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue in our app.
It seems to be a bug on the WebRTC side.
I was able to reproduce it in their test app (AppRTCMobile), and posted a bug report about it here:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11012

Please star it there :)

In the meantime it seems that forcing the codec to VP8 should fix the problem on the simulator (as a temporary workaround).

Comment: thank you.  A star from me for https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11012 :)

Comment: I am still seeing this issue even though it says it has been "Fixed" :(